# Not able to understand the deleting process while writing todo list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, html, ng-app

I am trying to write a todo application in Angularjs in  the following code.

```js
function write_controller($scope){
  $scope.todos = [{text:'hey all',done:false}, 
                 {text:'hello',done:false}];
  $scope.addtodo = function(){
  $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todopush,done:false});
    $scope.todopush = '';
  }
  $scope.delete = function(){
    var oldtodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldtodos, function(x){
      if (!x.done){
        $scope.todos.push(x);}
    });
  };
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
    <head>
     <script src =  
     "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js">   
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class = "basic_class" ng-controller = "write_controller">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "todo in todos"><input type = "checkbox" ng-model  
         ="todo.done">{{todo.text}}</input></li>
      </ul>
      <input type = "text"
        placeholder = "please add data here"
        ng-model="todopush">
      </input>
      <input type = "button" ng-click ="addtodo()" value ="Click me!!"></input>
      <input type = "button" ng-click = "delete()" ng-model="remove" value =  
       "remove!"></input>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the following code ,I have the following questions.
How is the delete operation working??

My understanding:
1)It pushes the existing array into a new array
2)It clears the exisitng array
3)Iterates over the  new array
3)Checking the done functionality??? (When it says !x.done , is it true or false???)
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You did this code? according to the code delete wont work

Comment: @Sajeetharan why not...works for me

Comment: If you're going to share code, do it using jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: @charlietfl yes i went through again, i was assuming oldtodos as todos

Comment: Do note that you are using a very old version of angular and if you were to upgrade would have to declare controller as part of the module. Support for global functions was dropped quite some time ago

Comment: OT: you can shorten the delete function to this: `$scope.todos = $scope.todos.filter(function(todo){ return !todo.done });` to your question: `!` means NOT, now read the line/if-block out loud, seriously, try it.

Answer (score 1):

Walk through the steps

```
$scope.delete = function() {
    // store existing todos array in variable
    var oldtodos = $scope.todos;
    // create new empty array for todos
    $scope.todos = [];
    // loop over previously stored todos
    angular.forEach(oldtodos, function(x) {//x is element of the array - a single todo object
      // if x.done is not truthy
      if (!x.done){
       // push this item into `$scope.todos`
       $scope.todos.push(x);
    });
}
```

Basically it only pushes the `done:false` into new version of `$scope.todos` which effectively removes the `done:true`

Comment: On a checkbox click ,how is the done getting updated from false to true???

Comment: `ng-model  
     ="todo.done"` see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: short answer is `ng-model` binds to the data model object and will change when the checkbox changes